# Finish activity behaviour depends on setOrientationScreen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I spent 3 days trying to solve this:

> 1. ActivityA starts ActivityB and exit.
> 2. User pres 'exit' button in activityB and I'm calling finishB.

I have put `NO_HISTORY` flag on `activityB`.Also I put `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when start `activityB`.
In manifest all activities are in `portrait` mode.

**This works fine when start activities without `setScreenOrientation` in onCreate.**

**Problem appear when I call `setScreenOrientation`**. This causes activity to be 'relaunched'.
And problem with properly finishin is beginning. Typicaly second attempt with finish doesnt relaunch `activityA`.
In some cases if `activityB` is created several times - losing focus etc. or calling some activities - several times calling finish solves problem :(.
It looks like I have multiple instances of (B) and have to clse all of them.

Comment: can you share code piece creating intent and launching B and A,B Manifest declaration

Comment: try setting `launchMode` of activityB in Manifest file to `singleInstance` and also set `configChange` to `orientation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For activityA put android:launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest.
When start activityB and finishA - because of 'singleinstance' system din't start activityA again.
:)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alertactivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
this.finish();
```

Comment: I'm using this flag. Read carefuly

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute to your activity tag in android manifest file

android:configChanges="orientation"